How many clusters are needed for applying cluster-robust standard errors in a SEM model?
I’m working on an SEM model with data from 1078 students, distributed across 13 schools (clusters). I’d like to apply cluster-robust standard errors, but I’m unsure whether 13 clusters is enough for this approach to provide reliable estimates. The cluster sizes range from 19 to 165 students per school.
Given the relatively small number of clusters (13), should I be concerned about the reliability of cluster-robust standard errors?
